# Autowiring services created with factory

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4, symfony-3.3

According to the official documentation, ***Autowiring** allows you to manage services in the container with minimal configuration. It reads the type-hints on your constructor (or other methods) and automatically passes the correct services to each method.*

So in order to have the service, the container must search for the ID that corresponds to the type-hint.

So, this are, the following interface & classes in my example

```
interface ServiceInterface
{
  public function doSomThing(): void;
}


class Service1 implements ServiceInterface {
     
      public function doSomThing(): void
      {
          echo "service1";
      }
}

class Service2 implements ServiceInterface {
     
        public function doSomThing(): void
        {
          echo "service2";
        }
}


class Service3 implements ServiceInterface {

     public function doSomThing(): void
     {
          echo "service3";
     }
}

//service.yml
DEL\Bundle\CoreBundle\Service\Base\Service1: ~ 

DEL\Bundle\CoreBundle\Service\Base\Service2:  ~

DEL\Bundle\CoreBundle\Service\Base\Service3:  ~
```

And finally, this is the **factory service** that creates a set of classes that implement the interface **ServiceInterface**.

```
//service.yml
DEL\Bundle\CoreBundle\Service\Base\ServiceInterface:
    autowire: false
    factory: ['@delcore.factory.service', serviceChoice]


class ServiceFactory {

    public function serviceChoice(string $param): ServiceInterface
    {
       switch ($param) {
           case 'label1':
              return new Service1();
           break;
            case 'label2':
             return new Service2();
            break;
            case 'label3':
             return new Service3();
            break;

    } 
}
```

The problem is that the method returns an object that implements **ServiceInterface** which cannot be found by container through "autowiring".

What can I do? knowing that you don't want to remove the **factory** entry from the **service.interface** configuration.

Comment: Instead of an id of service.interface, use an id of DEL\Bundle\CoreBundle\Service\Base\ServiceInterface and get rid of the class attribute.  That will allow you to typehint against ServiceInterface.  However, you will also have to add the $param value to your service definition or bind it.

Comment: As an alternative approach, you might want to take a look at [service locators](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_subscribers_locators.html).

Comment: Yes, i forget to put  DEL\Bundle\CoreBundle\Service\Base\ServiceInterface as service ID

Comment: But the serviceChoice() is used by factory to generate one of the three services : Service1 or Service2 or Service3. So how can contanier guess what service is created ?

Comment: It can't.  It boils down to where the value of $param comes from.  If it is set at the application level (perhaps a parameter) then you just pass the value in the factory service definition.  If it is a request based value (different requests will inject different implementations) then you need to inject the RequestStack into your factory or perhaps use the service locator approach.

Comment: Keep in mind that your Service1,Service2... definitions are not doing you any good since your factory is new'ing them.  But again, with a service locator then the service definitions would be used.

Comment: Without a clear definition on where do you need these services, how are these services going to be consumed, and what are you using to decide which one you need, it's not possible to give you a meaningful answer. It's not unlikely you are pursuing the wrong strategy with the factory, or that you need to inject the factory directly and let the consumer decide what service it needs...

Comment: @Cerad I didn't have the chance to use service locator approach. So i ll check it

Comment: @yivi That's a sf 2.8 legacy application so i'd like to establish the autowiring.  I encountred this doc  https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#working-with-interfaces . That is to say in the case where we have an interface as type-hint.